# Render ASP.Net PlaceHolder .ToString(), not to page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've searched around and have not been able to find an good solution. I have a custom extension to a `PlaceHolder` control that will contain expressions that I would like to take the string output of without having to call `control.Render()`, since that call automatically writes the contents out to the page.

Does anybody know how to get the would be rendered content into a string and prevent the page from containing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The often-regurgitated, slightly dated code for this goes something like:

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you prevent the page from *also* rendering the content of the control? [Resolved] Set the control Visible to false after rendering it.